# 90s B Horror Film about Splicing Human DNA with some fish DNA?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I've been trying to find this movie for a solid year or so now and the lack of ANY information on it makes me think I'm making this up. I saw it when I was young so 1990-1996 is the best I can do time frame wise.

From what I remember the movie is about a Scientist who splices his own DNA with that of a fish hes been experimenting with. I want to say it's a generically altered Zebra Fish but I'm not certain of that at all. It's your typical "creature hides in the shadows and kills his victims" kind of movie. The only other thing I remember about it is at the end someone brings in the same kind of generically altered fish in one of those "won it at the carnival" bags. Credits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the **1995** horror film, **"Shadow Creature"**.

[image]

> Detective Brighton investigates a series of unusually gruesome murders
>   and is soon caught in a web of intrigue involving a mad scientist, a
>   beautiful woman, a power mad politician, and one very ferocious
>   monster. Their secret lies in a mysterious formula which could unlock
>   the secrets of immortality... and on a less positive note, also cause
>   the mass mutation of all life on earth! The bodies pile up as everyone
>   scrambles for possession of the formula. It culminates in a climactic
>   showdown whose outcome will determine the fate of all mankind! ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114403/?ref_=kw_li_tt))
>
> A detective discovers that a series of local murders is somehow linked
>   to a hair tonic formula with some unusual properties. When some of the
>   tonic is accidentally spilled into a tank of Zebra Mussels. ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114403/reviews?ref_=tt_urv))

[Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLYX9cOBHyU)

Comment: You are my hero. That's exactly it. I have tired so hard to find this. Thank you so very much. The name "Creature in the Darkness" was always something that I thought it might be named or a variant of that. It's nice to know I wasn't too terribly off base. Thank you once again, you saved my sanity. Edit: It was Zebra Mussels! Oh man, I am so happy right now.